# Странное поведение размера шрифта при программной установке значения

Tags: java, android

Если задаю размер шрифта непосредственно в xml, то все отображается нормально.

```
android:textSize="@dimen/textMM"
```

Если задаю программно, то шрифт получается огромным:

```
actFontSize = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textMM);
btn.setTextSize(actFontSize);
```

У меня есть несколько dimens.xml с размерами в зависимости от ширины экрана.
То ли при программном задании он берет из другой папки, то ли я где-то накосячил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для установки размера шрифта есть 2 метода:

- `setTextSize(float size)` упрощенный способ установки
- `setTextSize(int complex_unit, float size)` полноценный способ установки

Первый метод (простой) всегда вызывает второй (полноценный) и передаёт входной размер и `COMPLEX_UNIT_PX`.

У вас несоответствие между `xml` и `java` только в типе меры. Для устранения проблемы воспользуйтесь полноценным методом передав туда ваш тип меры из `xml`.

Возможные значения [параметра complex_unit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html)

Например, для размера, указанного в единицах *sp* следует использовать константу:

[`TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#COMPLEX_UNIT_SP)

Comment: я позволил себе немного дополнить ваш ответ

Comment: Премного благодарен :)

Comment: Попробовал: btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,actFontSize);  Ничего не изменилось :(.

Comment: Вывел на консоль System.out.println(actFontSize); - получаю 120.0 А в xml стоит 50sp!

Comment: Все разобрался - надо размер в пикселях было ставить.

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо большое zTrap и pavlofff . Долго тупил но наконец разобрался.

```
actFontSize = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textMM);
```

Переводит размер в SP в размер в пикселях.
Поэтому и выходит 50SP превращается в 120PX.
Поэтому и при установке

`btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,actFontSize);`

надо ставить пиксели **UNIT_PX**.